# How can I make sure that my Android app is only available on the Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, galaxy-tab

I want to set up my Android app so that it can only be downloaded/installed on the Samsung Galaxy Tab. I've looked at guides like "[Five Steps to Future Hardware Happiness](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/five-steps-to-future-hardware-happiness.html)," but I haven't gotten much out of them. The Galaxy-Tab-only requirement is from the client that I'm building this app for - specifically, he wants to target just the Galaxy Tab P-1000 model, not other Tabs.

How can I set up my app so that the Android Market knows it should only be available to this specific model of device?

Comment: Why that particular model?  Why not do what the article suggests, i.e. restrict your apps to devices that provide all of the APIs that your app needs?

Comment: This is the requirement from my client.He want this thing in my application.I want to use my app only on Samsung Galaxy Tab model P-1000 not on others. How it is Possible. Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on Google Play itself, by adding all devices except the one you wish to support to the "Manually Excluded" list of your store listing. More information is available here:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017

Comment: I have posted that question one year back when i was just stated to  work in android. That time i was totally unaware about these things.

Answer (score 2):

[android.os.Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) contains properties you are interested in.

Build.MODEL, Build.PRODUCT and Build.MANUFACTURER should give you the info you need. They are all String objects.

And also, before installation u cant detect the device model, but after installing the app, you can detect the device model using Build.Model attribute and run ur application as accordingly..

Comment: Check this:http://android-sample-code.blogspot.in/#!http://android-sample-code.blogspot.com/2011/11/show-device-information.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer kanika. I will try this thing in my app

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can detect the hardware manufacturer or the model type using standard android apis.